# Add subview through initWithFrame. UINavigationBar size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have a View with UINavigationBar:
**AppDelegate**:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

_homeScreen = [[PrepareScreen alloc] init];
self.mainViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithScreenDef:[self.homeScreen projectHomeScreen] AndBounds:self.window.bounds];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

And then i have a class

```
MyViewController : UIView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

And in my **.h** file i have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];
}
```

After that i have a wrong height of a screen. I want that my myTableView have a size.height-49.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Init the tableView with `CGRectZero` in `viewDidLoad` method and then in the method `viewWillAppear:` set the `self.myTableView.frame` as in this method the view's geometry is already set and `self.view.bounds` will be correct. So in general: init views in `viewDidLoad`, but set their geometry in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: One addition only, you can create your table view in viewWillAppear:, as long as, you're not doing a heavy operation. Generally use viewWillAppear for lightweight operations - mostly geometry adjustments.

Comment: OK, so when i want to put data from my model class is a better to do this in viewDidLoad, and when i'm trying resize cells or change background color (for example) I should use a viewWillAppear, right?

Comment: Yes, only if your data fetching from the model takes long time you may load it in different thread, but start in viewDidLoad...

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
CGRect r = initWithFrame:self.view.bounds;
r.size.height -= 49.0;
self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:r];
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yes, this is obvious solution, but I hope for something more universal. Maybe getting actual free space size.